# How to make custom ajax handler in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i'm trying to make custom ajax handler in wordpress because the admin-ajax.php is taking to long to handle ajax requests from 7s to 10s so i google it and mange to do some custom ajax-handler.php like this

```
<?php
if (is_ajax_request()) {
    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
            case "test": test_function(); break;
        }
    }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax_request() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function()
{
    $response = wc_get_product(1463);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

and i send first the response as text `$response = "test"` and the ajax call was taking 300ms but when trying to call function from another file like `$response = wc_get_product(1463);` it throws an error in the response `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wc_get_product() in C:\wamp\www\....`
and i tried to make custom wordpress ajax handel using this  [ajaxflow plugin](https://github.com/EkAndreas/ajaxflow) but it the seams thing so please please how can i call the functions from another files and many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load wp to use its functions

```
require_once 'wp-load.php' //note find the file relative to your files location or do a dynamic url to find .. e.g. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

if (is_ajax_request()) {
    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
            case "test": test_function(); break;
        }
    }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax_request() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function()
{
    $response = wc_get_product(1463);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

But wp-ajax itself is probably not the issue, did you test wp-ajax with simple output like 'test' ?

Comment: Note: When including wp-load.php, it's better to start with the ajax file's directory and work your way back up to the Wordpress root than using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, since WP could be installed in a subdirectory and you may not have any idea what that is/will be (i.e. a custom ajax handler in a plugin)